# Debugging javascript code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, debugging

My script part in my php page is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    alert('Out');
    if (<?php echo $delFlag; ?> == 1) {
        alert('ting');
    } 
</script>
```

While the code below is what I get from the Chrome Developers tool (Resource>XHR) (which I'm using for debugging)

```
<!-- For javascripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" >
alert('Out');
    if (1 == 1) {
        alert('ting');
    }
</script>
```

The alerts are not popping up.

What is wrong with my codes??

**Update**

I've my codes in a file add-line.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
//  $(function() {

        if (<?php echo $timer; ?> == 1) {
            //alert('Line');

            var timenow = <?php echo time(); ?>;
            var dataPass = 'lineId=' + <?php echo $lineId; ?> + '&storyId=' + <?php echo $storyId; ?> + '&timenow=' + timenow;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "proc/updateDb.php",
                data: dataPass,
                cache: false,
                success: function(){
                    // Show error if error is there

                }
            }); 
        } 
//  });
</script>
```

Now in the updateDb.php I m processing some CRUD thing using the POST values and then determine `$delFlag` value. Then at the end of this file, I've my scripts as (same as the first one above)

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        alert('Out');
        if (<?php echo $delFlag; ?> == 1) {
            alert('ting');
        } 
    </script>
```

But this script is not being executed at all it seems.

Comment: The code is correct, the problem must lie somewhere else than in the code.

Comment: js is already enabled. It must be somewhere else then. Not been able to figure out where for hours..

Comment: you can check that it works by yourself: take the code above, put it in a blank "test.html" file and open it with a browser. The alerts must show up.

Comment: @ptamzz - `Resource>XHR` ? Do you mean to say you are using ajax?

Comment: If you have any error prior to this code is executed, there will be no alert. What does the error console say?

Comment: @Reigel: yes I'm using ajax. This page is being called by another page using ajax

Comment: @ptamzz - please include the code for that. It would help us help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I notice you are using ajax, you that script would run if you add it to the DOM.

for example, if you use `$.ajax()`

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'some/url/',
   type: 'html',
   method: 'get',
   success: function(data){
      $('head').append(data);
      // data here would be the response from the server...
   }
});
```

Comment: You are great man.. thanks.. been struggling for the whole day with this. :) Working now.

Answer (score 1):

You tried this:

```
<!-- For javascripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var number = parseInt("<?php echo $delFlag; ?>");
    alert('Out');
    if (number == 1) {
        alert('ting');
    }
</script>
```

You can do it without the quotes if you want.. but if you using some editor they whill markit as a error.

Answer (score 0):

Try like that. Error message will prompt and try to fix it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Out');
    try
      {
        if (<?php echo $delFlag; ?> == 1) {
            alert('ting');
        } 
      }
    catch(err)
      {
      alert(err.description);
      }
</script>
```